# Remove one level of file extension from filename in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have a Bash script that loops through files and masks them. The files are gzipped and I need to gunzip them first before passing them as argument to a Python program as shown in script below. The problem is that variable `$i` does not turn into the unzipped version of the filename. The file name before unzipping is `my-log-1.c.log.gz`. After running gunzip on the file as below I want to pass `my-log-1.c.log` as the argument to the `masker.sh` script, not the `.gz` version. How would I do this?

```
#!bin/bash

cd /home/logs

  for i in *
     gunzip $i
     do
       python masker.py $i  # python program masks files 
     rm $i
     echo "masked_file and removed =  $i"
   done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [basename](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/basename/):

```
for i in; do
  gunzip "$i"
  i=$(basename "$i" .gz)
  python masker.py "$i"  # python program masks files 
  rm $i
  echo "masked_file and removed =  $i"
done
```

The first argument is the filename and the second one is the extension you want to remove.

Comment: it turns  my-log-1.c.log.gz into  my-log-1.c.log and stores it in `i`

Comment: And files that dont have .gz extension to begin with in the directory, would my script screw those up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the program below:

```
for i in; do
    gunzip "$i"
    i=$(echo $i|rev|cut -d'.' -f2-|rev)
    python masker.py "$i"  # python program masks files 
    rm $i
    echo "masked_file and removed =  $i"
done
```

Comment: Your implementation of stripping the period is rather ugly. It will be slow, and feels like a kludge.